# jQuery animate back when clicked anywhere on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function (){
            $(".links").click(function(){ 
            $('.slider').stop(true,false).animate({right:  "0" }, 800, 'easeOutQuint' ); },
        function(){ 
            $(".slider").stop(true,false).animate({right: "-200" }, 800, 'easeInQuint' ); },1000);
        });

   </script>
```

I am building a little slider on my website. The slider position is `right: -200`. It slides to position `right:0` I want to animate it back to position `right: -200` after clicking anywhere else on the page.

I tried all the ways which failed. `toggle(slide)` works good but doesn't looks good.

Comment: This could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but I want to animate slider back, not hide it.

Comment: Well, just adapt the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, here you go

```
$(document).click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   if($(e.target).closest("your_slider_selector").length) return;

   //here you can do what you want
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind click on all document, stop current animation, run new animation.
`$(document).click(function () {
    $('.slider').stop(true).animate({right: -200}, 500);
});`

Answer (score 0):

Store the CSS value in a variable before you animate the slider:

```
var right = $('.slider').css("right");
```

And then you can just use the variable:

```
$('.slider').stop(true).animate({right: right}, 800);
```

Here an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ctdjkrLx/2/